# I am unable to get a list of bluetooth printers in iOS in flutter application

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to get a list of bluetooth printers in iOS in flutter application.

The application is running perfect in android and I am also able to print from android device.

I am using a package called flutter_blue_plus 1.5.2
I installed in pubspec.yaml :

```
-> flutter_blue_plus: ^1.3.1
```

My iOS info.plist

```
 <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key> 
    <string>Need BLE permission</string> 
    <key> NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need BLE permission</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> 
    <string> Need Location permission</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> 
    <string>Need Location permission</string> 
    <key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need Location permission</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app uses bluetooth</string>
```

I am scanning for bluetooth devices like this :

```
FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;
  List<ScanResult> scanResult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    findDevices();
  }

  void findDevices() {
    // if(await Permission.b)
    if (flutterBlue.isOn != null) {
      flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4));
      flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
        setState(() {
          scanResult = results;
        });
      });
      flutterBlue.stopScan();
    }
  }
```

The error I am getting while trying to debug the app in our iOS

```
2023-05-26 00:30:01.250916+0530 Runner[1044:250516] [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x282d5c000> can only accept this command while in the powered on state
2023-05-26 00:30:01.288553+0530 Runner[1044:250516] [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x282d5c000> can only accept this command while in the powered on state
```

Answer (score 0):

From implementation point of view I would suggest to only start scanning if the `.isOn` returns true, as you are currently start scanning even when the `.isOn` returns false, which indicates that the bluetooth stack is not ready. This explains the error you can see in the debugging console.

To be independent from the timing of the initialisation of your Widget, I would suggest to rely on the stream `.state` and only operate on the `FlutterBluePlus.instance` when the state is `BluetoothState.On`.